# Check in preprocessor that g++ is called with -fopenmp

Tags: c++, g++, c-preprocessor, openmp

I have my code that uses OpenMP and I build it with `g++` like this:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O3 -fopenmp main.cpp -o helloworld
```

Now, for debugging and testing purposes, I sometimes want to build the code without OpenMP with something like that:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O3 main.cpp -o helloworld
```

The code will not build because OpenMP functions are not linked (`-fopenmp` is not used). So my idea was to use some preprocessor magic, something like that:

```
#ifdef OPENMP
// run OpenMP-specific code
#else
// run this code only if -fopenmp was not set
#endif
```

Is that possible? The problem might be that `-fopenmp` is only used for linking OpenMP library thus might be not known/used during preprocessor phase of build.

Comment: `g++ -DOPENMP -fopenmp` ?

Comment: hmmm that is very easy and will definitely work :) I will use this now but still interesting if it's possible to avoid this redundancy. I am just afraid that I might easily forget and use `-fopenmp` without `-DOPENMP` :)

Comment: also, if I forget to add `-DOPENMP`, there will be no error during the build (the preprocessor will just branch to the `#else` part)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenMP standard proposes a macro which is exactly meant to be used in such cases: [`_OPENMP`](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse10.html#x38-450002.2)

This macro is defined if and only if the code is compiled with support to OpenMP activated. Furthermore, although it isn't your problem here, the macro is defined to reflect the version of the standard the compiler is supporting.

More precisely, the macro, when set, is defined with the following format:
`YYYYMM` where `YYYY` denotes the year and `MM` denotes the month of adoption of the standard that is supported. Since the standard is regularly incorporating news feature, this permits to check in the code whether or not a feature that is needed will be supported by checking if `_OPENMP` as a value greater or equal to the minimum one that is needed.

Finally, and just as a remark, you might want also to consider the following alternative to address your issue. Indeed, if for debugging reasons you want your code not to be compiled with OpenMP activated, but you still want it to work even if it calls OpenMP specific functions (like `omp_get_num_threads()`), you can just replace the **`-fopenmp`** switch with **`-lgomp`** everywhere. With this simple trick won't have your OpenMP directives enabled, but you'll still link the OpenMP runtime where the functions you need are defined. Ans since you won't be in any active parallel region when calling them, they will do exactly what you'd like them to do.

Comment: I've tried to compile my code with `g++ -std=c++17 -O3 -lgomp main.cpp -o helloworld` and got the error: ```/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cczRLSJu.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x256): undefined reference to `omp_get_num_threads'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x161e): undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status```

Comment: Oops. Right. I'd forgotten that the order matters here. `-lgomp` must come after `main.cpp` as the linker resolves dependencies in objects from left to right. So before main.cpp no OpenMP object is needed. Therefore it doesn't actually link libgomp. And after main.cpp, libgomp isn't accessible any more. So just try changing the order and that should work.